# Preventing a fixed header from hiding text with CSS

Tags: css, layout

Given `<div id='pageheader'>`, with the following CSS:

```
#pageheader { position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 35px; }
body { margin-top: 35px; }
```

I have a header that stays fixed at the top of the page. The problem is when the user clicks on a link to another part of the same page, the link's target appears *under* the header. I'm not sure how to prevent this.

**Edit:** I ended up using JQuery to give internal links a smooth scroll, which eliminated this problem.

```
$("span.sect1, span.sect2").click(function(){
    var target = '#' + $(this).find("a").attr('href').match(/#(.*)$/)[1];       
    var position = $(target).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: (position.top -40)}, "slow");
});
$("a.xref").click(function(){
    var target = '#' + $(this).attr('href').match(/#(.*)$/)[1];     
    var position = $(target).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: (position.top -40)}, "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where before you might have:

```
<h1 id="target">Get here with #target</h1>
```

Try this:

```
<h1><a id="target" style="position: relative; top: -35px;"></a>Get here with #target</h1>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need a solution that works by using CSS. The HTML is generated from docbook XML, and the links are to ids, not hidden anchors

Comment: Well, you could apply the CSS to the `h1`: `position: relative; top: -35px; padding-top: 35px;`

Comment: While that works, that technique also changes other parts of the page layout. For example, some headers have a background color and span across the page, and changing the padding on them like that increases their visible height. It's also difficult for me to anticipate all the objects on the page that might be the target of a link.

Comment: `:target` - this psuedo-class targets whatever element is the target of a link ;)